# What is the difference between "Start-Process python ex.py" and "python ex.py" in powershell?

Tags: python, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am learning powershell and trying to start a python service using the powershell IDE. I came to know I can start the python services either by one of these commands.

```
Start-Process python example.py
python example.py
```

Though both of these gives the same result, I am curious to know what is the difference between these two in terms of internal functions and which is better to use?

Comment: If you run the console version of PowerShell (`powershell.exe`), `Start-Process` will start a console executable in a separate console, whereas the second command will run a console executable in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are calling python.exe . 
As for the python.exe there is no difference to run .

During python installation , if you selected ***'add python to PATH'*** to add path of python.exe into environment variables ,then, you can run python.exe directly in PS .

If you didn't check it , you may need to locate the folder contains python.exe to run  ***.py*** file .

In addition , python.exe can be run under other user privilege using 'start-process'  with parameter '-credential' . If you run python.exe in PS console it will inherits user privilege of PS console .